# How to associate events of datagrids from different forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagrid, event-handling

There are many forms in my current application (these forms are inherited from one base class), and there are too many different datagrids in these forms. Each datagrid has its own event handlers. And there is an possibility to create a form with large-scaled datagrid for each datagrid in this application. I need to associate some events of 'parent' and 'child' datagrids (such as selection change, double-clicks on rows, etc.) - when an event raises in 'parent' form it should be raised in 'child form' and vice versa.

Is there a simple way to associate these events? (by using an intermediate class, for example)

I'm using winforms, vb.net.

Comment: Could you provide a simplified example of the type of thing you'd like to do?  You can have multiple event handlers for the same event, or you can re-raise another event, but without more details, it's hard to give you a specific answer.

Comment: As I sad I need to associate events of 'parent' and 'child' datagrids: when we click on a row in parent datagrid this row becomes selected - and in the same time the same row in child datagrid should be selected too (the same actions with parent datagrid should be when we click on a row in child datagrid). In this case I thought to use something like `AddHandler childGrid.RowClick, AddressOf parentGrid.RowClicked` but event handlers of parent datagrid are protected and I can't get access to them from an intermediate class (and I don't want to make them public)